# Deleting a line from a specific variable

Tags: bash, sed

Using sed I'm able to delete a line of code inside the command prompt. When i go to use it inside a bash script and use a variable it doesn't delete it.

```
function remove_user {
echo "Input user you would like to delete"
read rui
if grep -q  $rui database.txt ;
then
    echo "Are you sure yu want to delete this user?"
    echo "(Y/N)"
    read input3
    if [ $input3 == "Y" ] || [ $input3 == "y" ] ;
    then

            sed -i '/"$rui"/d' ./databse.txt
            echo "User Deleted"
            echo "returning to the main menu..."
            echo "$rui"
            #sleep 1 ; clear

    elif [ $input3 == "N" ] || [$input3 == "n" ] ;
    then
            echo "returning to main menu..."
            sleep 1 ; clear
    else
            echo "input invalid"
            echo "returning to main menu..."
            sleep 1 ; clear
    fi
 else
    echo " user not found"
    echo "returning to main menu..."
    sleep 1 ; clear
fi
```

My database looks like this

Larry:Larry@hotmail.com:Larry Bob:ATC:4.0

Not sure what the issue could be because the code works just not with a variable

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the variable visible to the shell by breaking back out of the single-quote delimited sed script briefly. You do that by adding a terminating single quote before the variable, and a starting one again after it:

```
sed -i '/'"$rui"'/d' ./databse.txt
```

The reason you don't just use double quotes around the whole script is that sets you up for surprises later when the shell interprets you're whole script instead of just the variable you want it to expand. e.g.:

```
$ echo "money is nice" | sed 's/money/$$/'
$$ is nice

$ foo="money"; echo "money is nice" | sed 's/'"$foo"'/$$/'
$$ is nice

$ foo="money"; echo "money is nice" | sed "s/$foo/$$/"
6756 is nice
```

That last one happens because the double quotes expose your whole script to the shell before sed sees it and the shell interprets `$$` as the current PID.

Comment: `sed -i "/${rui}/d" ./databse.txt` so no loosing quote and double quote. Maybe a bit secure the possible content of `rui` especialy witw quote and char like this (and real security also, due to batch execution)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu My answer explains why you should not do that. Curly braces just separate variable names from otherwise concatenated text (`echo "${foo}bar"` as one solution to `echo "$foobar"`) and allow for subsitution (e.g. `echo "${foo##x}"`) and array operations but they don't protect the variable from shell interpretation so `sed "/${rui}/d"` would be no better than `sed "/$rui/d"`.

Comment: I don't say my version is more secure, i said it to secure the content and it's just easier to read. Your sample give no surprise (interpretation of $$ is not part of the variable foo content) and seems no more secure than the whole encapsulation with double quote. Rule are to escape  inside the sed if double quote so `"s/$foo/\$\$/"`. Do you have a sample where simple quote on surrounding info (so keeping `"$rui"`) will avoid problem with rui content ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. Yes that example is no surprise because I chose an extremely clear, obvious case to demonstrate the issue. My point is simply that if you delimit the script with single quotes and only break back into shell for the minimal section necessary to expand your variable(s) then you don't have to worry about escaping characters anywhere else in your script which makes your scripts clearer, briefer, and less error-prone.

Comment: Your explaination was clear; I just try to find a case where `"/$rui/"` is less secure than `'/'"$rui"'/'`

Comment: That case doesn't exist since sed sees `/<contents of rui>/` either way, it's just a bad habit to get into since it's only equivalent in situations like that where there's nothing else the shell will interpret and then you get used to doing it that way and then one day you're doing it in a script where you didn't notice there IS something for the shell to interpret.